# eclipse IDE windows 7 os importing choco package

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, constraint-programming, choco

i am trying to install the java constraint solver package called choco : http://choco.sourceforge.net/first.html

please let me know how to go about, i have tried several times, with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just like any other java library: **Add the jar to your classpath** (see Eclipse preferences, java build path, add jar folder) and then follow one of their examples.

If they are in maven central (looks like [choco isn't yet](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cchoco)), you could configure it similar to [maven configuring Drools Planner](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-planner/html_single/index.html#d0e155) (an alternative constraint programming lib in java).